# Why does an accepted answer earn 15 rep?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, reputation

Question in title. In contrast, an accepted answer in math.stackexchange.com earns 35 rep for the answerer. Is it a general thing or is there a specific reason for this difference? And should we discuss about this or is it fixed?

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answers have always been worth 15 points, this is the same on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) as it is here.

Often an accepted answer (like any good answer) is accompanied by upvotes, which would account for the difference; I believe this is all lumped together in the reputation tally on the status bar (which could explain the confusion), but listed separately on the reputation tab in the user profile.

Comment: I see now. Should I delete this question because of my misunderstanding?

Comment: @mezhang might as well keep it up; it's a common confusion, someone else might have the same question later.